# Microsoft 365 Dynamic group validation rule error (Memberof)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm looking to create a dynamic MS365 group, I simply want to apply the following dynamic rule

`user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['objectID1','objectID2'])`

When going through [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-rule-member-of) this should be fully supported, infact I have groups created months ago which use this exact syntax. When copying rules directly from these working groups, created exactly the same way, I get the same error:

> Failed to create group x. Dynamic membership rule validation error: Wrong property applied

Any thoughts?

I attempted to create a Microsoft 365 Dynamic groups within Azure AD. When creating it with a specific rule used to capture members from multiple other assigned sec groups I am given the error

> Failed to create group x. Dynamic membership rule validation error: Wrong property applied

Despite this working on groups in prod. I would expect this to function and create without issue.

Comment: For anyone who reads / has a similar issue - I discussed this with MS Support who have suggested it's an issue specifically resulting from AAD to Entra and given this is a preview feature it's unlikely to be "fixed" soon.

Comment: New comment, this now appears resolved from Microsoft's end.

Answer (score 0):

We have attempted to create dynamic rules via PowerShell, Graph, in Identity Governance access package auto assignment policies and getting the same error results everywhere.

Previously created rules continue to work and add and remove users as expected.

The only workaround we have at the moment is to copy and paste source group rules into the derivative groups that we would normally create memberof rules for.